# problem with laravel and vue.js | Error: Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, npm, webpack

I recently got this error whenever I install vue in laravel using the following commands:

```
composer require laravel/UI
PHP artisan up vue
php artisan ui vue --auth
npm install && npm run dev
```

I get this new error and its the first time that happened to me:

```
 Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/rules/DescriptionDataMatcherRulePlugin'
Require stack:
- C:\wamp64\www\projects\quizapp\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\plugin-webpack5.js
- C:\wamp64\www\projects\quizapp\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\plugin.js
- C:\wamp64\www\projects\quizapp\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\index.js
- C:\wamp64\www\projects\quizapp\node_modules\laravel-mix\src\components\Vue.js
- C:\wamp64\www\projects\quizapp\node_modules\laravel-mix\src\components\ComponentRegistrar.js
- C:\wamp64\www\projects\quizapp\node_modules\laravel-mix\src\Mix.js
- C:\wamp64\www\projects\quizapp\node_modules\laravel-mix\setup\webpack.config.js
- C:\wamp64\www\projects\quizapp\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js
- C:\wamp64\www\projects\quizapp\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\bootstrap.js
- C:\wamp64\www\projects\quizapp\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js
- C:\wamp64\www\projects\quizapp\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (C:\wamp64\www\projects\quizapp\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\wamp64\www\projects\quizapp\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\plugin-webpack5.js:6:42)
    at Module._compile (C:\wamp64\www\projects\quizapp\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\quizapp\\node_modules\\vue-loader\\lib\\plugin-webpack5.js',
    'C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\quizapp\\node_modules\\vue-loader\\lib\\plugin.js',
    'C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\quizapp\\node_modules\\vue-loader\\lib\\index.js',
    'C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\quizapp\\node_modules\\laravel-mix\\src\\components\\Vue.js',
    'C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\quizapp\\node_modules\\laravel-mix\\src\\components\\ComponentRegistrar.js',
    'C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\quizapp\\node_modules\\laravel-mix\\src\\Mix.js',
    'C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\quizapp\\node_modules\\laravel-mix\\setup\\webpack.config.js',
    'C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\quizapp\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\lib\\webpack-cli.js',
    'C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\quizapp\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\lib\\bootstrap.js',
    'C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\quizapp\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\bin\\cli.js',
    'C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\quizapp\\node_modules\\webpack\\bin\\webpack.js'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ watch: `mix watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\zzzab\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-05T07_08_51_267Z-debug.log
```

and I tried to make a new laravel project and didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i have the solution,

**1- Delete the** `node_modules` **folder using the file explorer and delete** `package-lock.json`  **as well**.

**2- Run** `npm install` **command**.

**3- Run** `npm run dev` **or** `npm run watch` **for auto mix when ever change made**.